# How to write and debug a PowerShell module using VIsual Studio Powershell Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, powershell-module

I'd like to take advantage of Visual Studio's debugging capabilities when writing PowerShell scripts, especially PowerShell modules. Thus, I have installed the PowerShell tools for Visual Studio. I created a new PowerShell module project - but I can't figure out how to properly run and debug?

When running such a project I'd expect that the module is loaded and all functions are available in the debug window - and that any code execution would stop at break points.

However, I can't manage to run a module that way. In Solution Properties => Advanced => Entry point I can only select ps1 files. I've RTFM at https://docs.poshtools.com/ but didn't find anything about modules. Just to avoid any confusion, I am not developing anything with C# or VB in this project, just pure PS. I have been developing PS before using Visual Studio Code, but as I am more comfortable with Visual Studio 2019 I might be able to use it for PS development as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just write it as a function, set your breakpoints and when youre done rename it to a module and rename the file to psm1 file ?

Comment: That of course would work. But the idea would be to put it in source control and have people check out and use the current version. While it would be possible to always copy the ps1 contents to the psm file, it would be a much more fluent process if one could work directly on the module. I mean, how is this PSM project functionality meant to be used after all? But thanks for the suggestion, I'd consider it if it turns out to be the only way possible.